# What methods are available to implement a local cache of a large DB driven data?

Tags: database, caching, replication, time-series, distributed-caching

My company maintains a number of large time series databases of process data. We implement a replica of a subset at a pseudo-central location. I access the data from my laptop. The data access over our internal WAN even to the pseudo-central server is fairly expensive (time).

I would like to cache data requests locally on my laptop so that when I access it for a second time I actually pull from a local db.

There is a fairly ugly client side DAO that I can wrap to maintain the cache but I'm unsure how I can get the "official" client applications to talk to the cache easily. I have the freedom to write my own "client" graphing/plotting system, and already have a custom application that does some data mining already implemented. The custom application dumps data into .csv files that are manually moved around on a very ad-hoc basis.

What is the best approach to this sort of caching/synchonization? What tools could implement the cache?

For further info, the raw data set I have estimated at approx 5-8Tb of RAW time series data per year, with at least half of the data being very compressible. I only want to cache say a few hundred Mb locally. When ad-hoc queries are made on the data it tends to be very repetitive over very small chunks of the data.

Comment: so you need to intercept client applications calls and make them return data from the cache instead of the db?

Comment: what is the communication protocol?

Comment: in case the client applications use java and jdbc drivers, there might be an option to use gridgain distributed cache and its jdbc driver.